# delete directory with special character in filename

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards, rm, special-characters

I have these tricky directories that I can't figure out how to delete. If I run

```
ls -ld *
```

I get…

> drwxrwxr-x  7 user1        taskfmri     2048 Jan 22 15:26 857263
>   drwxrwx---  4 user2      taskfmri     2048 Jan 23 16:32 857263?

There are ~50 of these directories with '?' in the ls. Unfortunately, the '?' isn't literally a ?, but is instead some special character that the terminal can't display

What is the best way to remove all of these directories with unknown special characters, without deleting the almost-identically named good directories?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all your directories have names made of digits and then a special char (neither digit nor letter), you could use

`find  -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex "./[0-9]*[^0-9a-zA-Z]" -exec rm -r {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue, and could not work out how to delete `./?d` from CLI.

If you have `Vim` installed, it comes with a visual browser called `netrw`.

1. You can open the directory by using `vim ./` (to open current directory)
2. Use the `up` and `down` arrows to place the cursor over the file.
3. Press `D` (uppercase `d`) to delete the file.
4. Press `y` to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do this?

```
rm -r 857263?
```

Answer (score 0):

I had such directory:

```
$ ll
total 0
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 57 Oct  2 12:41  mydir.d
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 38 Oct  2 12:30 'mydir.d }}'
```

And at first i thought that the `'` is part of the name of the directory.
I couldn't delete it in any way even `rm -rf -- '*}*'` or `rm -rf -- '*\}*'`

I ended up removing the directory via its inode number

```
# First review the files & inodes
$ ls -li
total 0
1234578 drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 57 Oct  2 12:41  mydir.d
6549872 drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 38 Oct  2 12:30 'mydir.d }}'
# ^^^
# inode

# 2nd: run with find
$ find . -inum 6549872
./mydir.d }}     <= this is where i noticed there are no commas

# 3rd: remove the dir via inode
$ find . -inum 6549872 -exec rm -rf "{}" \;
```